# Getting output of shell command in bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, ubuntu-14.04

I have a uniq -c output, that outputs about 7-10 lines with the count of each pattern that was repeated for each unique line pattern. I want to store the output of my uniq -c file.txt into a bash array. Right now all I can do is store the output into a variable and print it. However, bash currently thinks the entire output is just one big string.

How does bash recognize delimiters? How do you store UNIX shell command output as Bash arrays?

Here is my current code:

```
proVar=`awk '{printf ("%s\t\n"), $1}' file.txt | grep -P 'pattern' | uniq -c`
echo $proVar
```

And current output I get:

```
587 chr1 578 chr2 359 chr3 412 chr4 495 chr5 362 chr6 287 chr7 408 chr8 285 chr9 287 chr10 305 chr11 446 chr12 247 chr13 307 chr14 308 chr15 365 chr16 342 chr17 245 chr18 252 chr19 210 chr20 193 chr21 173 chr22 145 chrX 58 chrY
```

Here is what I want:

```
proVar[1] = 2051
proVar[2] = 1243
proVar[3] = 1068
...
proVar[22] = 814 
proVar[X] = 72
proVar[Y] = 13
```

In the long run, I'm hoping to make a barplot based on the counts for each index, where every 50 counts equals one "=" sign. It will hopefully look like the below

```
chr1 ===========
chr2 ===========
chr3 =======
chr4 =========
...
chrX ==
chrY =
```

Any help, guys?

Comment: Maybe you really need bash arrays, but I do my histograms at the end of a pipeline with awk, i.e. `awk '/pattern/{printf ("%s\t\n"), $1}' file.txt | sort | uniq -c | awk '{fn_mkThatHistogram($0)}'`, but YRMV. Good luck!

Comment: Using `grep -P` in conjunction with `awk` is pretty weird.  Given that `perl` is more ubiquitous than a `grep` that supports `-P`, why not just use `perl` for the first two parts of the pipe?

Comment: To answer your question, it's because I didn't know perl was a unix command (haha), and I don't know much about Perl in general. I was trained mostly in C and UNIX, so I usually stick to the popular UNIX commands for bash scripts. I used the -P option so I could have regular expression control for formatting my strings with \t \n and what not. I'll have a look into Perl though for sure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build the associative array, try this:

```
declare -A proVar
while read -r val key; do
  proVar[${key#chr}]=$val
done < <(awk '{printf ("%s\t\n"), $1}' file.txt | grep -P 'pattern' | uniq -c)
```

<sup>Note: This assumes that your command's output is composed of *multiple* lines, each containing *one* key-value pair; the single-line output shown in your question comes from passing `$proVar` to echo without double quotes.</sup>

- Uses a `while` loop to read each output line from a process substitution (`<(...)`).
- The *key* for each assoc. array entry is formed by stripping prefix `chr` from each input line's first whitespace-separated token, whereas the *value* is the rest of the line (after the separating space).

To then create the bar plot, use:

```
while IFS= read -r key; do
  echo "chr${key} $(printf '=%.s' $(seq $(( ${proVar[$key]} / 50 ))))"
done < <(printf '%s\n' "${!proVar[@]}" | sort -n)
```

<sup>Note: Using `sort -n` to sort the keys will put non-numeric keys such as `X` and `Y` *before* numeric ones in the output.</sup>

- `$(( ${proVar[$key]} / 50 ))` calculates the number of `=` chars. to display, using *integer* division in an arithmetic expansion.
- The purpose of `$(seq ...)` is to simply create as many *tokens* (arguments) as `=` chars. should be displayed (the tokens created are numbers, but their content doesn't matter).
- `printf '=%.s' ...` is a trick that effectively prints as many `=` chars. as there are arguments following the format string.
- `printf '%s\n' "${!proVar[@]}" | sort -n` sorts the keys of the assoc. array numerically, and its output is fed via a process substitution to the `while` loop, which therefore iterates over the keys in sorted order.

Comment: You are phenomenal - thank you!! I learned so much from your code and explanations. You would make an excellent instructor. :-)

Comment: @areyoujokingme: My pleasure; that's very kind of you to say. Allow me this general advice: For the benefit of both respondents and future readers: If an answer _solves_ your problem, please _accept it_ by clicking the large check mark next to it; if you find an answer _helpful_, please _up-vote_ it by clicking the up-arrow icon. (You may do both.)

Comment: I went to sleep last night realizing this - thank you for the reminder! I don't ask often enough to have to accept answers. Thanks again!

Comment: I have a "post-processing" question about your line below: proVar[${key#chr}]=$val. Can you explain what the #chr does? I really want to understand how the script knew to print the chrX, chrY and chrM and didn't just rely on the iterator value of $key, etc. Does that make sense? I'm doing a related take involving BASH arrays now that is not precisely like the above.

Comment: @areyoujokingme: `${key#chr}` is an instance of [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html): here it removes string `chr` from the _beginning_ (`#`) of the value of variable `$key`, if present.

Comment: Awesomeee. Thank you! SO, so, so helpful! It would have taken me about another day or two to find that, haha. :^]

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array in an assignment using parentheses:

```
proVar=(`awk '{printf ("%s\t\n"), $1}' file.txt | grep -P 'pattern' | uniq -c`)
```

There's no built-in way to create an associative array directly from input. For that you'll need an additional loop.

Comment: This does create an array, but not with the correct keys or values.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to create an associative array directly from output, I think you'll have to write a loop for that.